# About python multiple inheritance

Tags: python

```py
class base:
    def __init__(self):
        print('base')


class F0(base):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        print("F0")


class F1(F0):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        print("F1")


class F2(F0):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        print("F2")


class F3(F1, F2):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        print("F3")

# -------------------------------------
class Base_1():
    def __init__(self):
        print('base_1')

class Base_2():
    def __init__(self):
        print('base_2')
        
class Base_3(Base_1, Base_2):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        print("base_3")


if __name__ == '__main__':
    f3 = F3()
    print(F3.mro())

    base_3 = Base_3()
    print(Base_3.mro())
```

Output:

```
base
F0
F2
F1
F3
[<class '__main__.F3'>, <class '__main__.F1'>, <class '__main__.F2'>, <class '__main__.F0'>, <class '__main__.base'>, <class 'object'>]
base_1
base_3
[<class '__main__.Base_3'>, <class '__main__.Base_1'>, <class '__main__.Base_2'>, <class 'object'>]
```

Point I understand:

For `Base_3` class, it inherits `Base_1` and `Base_2`. In `Base_3`'s `init` function, if I call `super().__init__()` it only executes `Base_1`'s `init` function.

Point I don't understand:

2 classes (`F1`, `F2`) have a same father class (`F0`) who inherits from another class (`base`). Then if I call `super().__init__()` in F3 (which inherits `F1` and `F2`), it will execute **both** `F1` and `F2`'s `init` function.

Answer (score 1):

in case of `base_3` there is no MRO rules applied because `base_1` and `base_2` are not linked to each other by inheritance
so it means that simple inheritance tree search rules are applied in case of `base_3` => when you call `super` in `base_3` that `super` finds first `__init__` in `base_1` (cuz of `base_1` is lefter - `Base_3(Base_1, Base_2)`) and then nothing happens, `super` is worked 
but in case of `F3` its parents `F1` and `F2` has the same parent `F0` so it mean that `F0` is inherited by `F3` twice == diamond problem occures(!), and this diamond problem will be solved by MRO3 but not with simple inheritance like in case of `base_3`

Comment: Thans for your reply! So applying "MRO" means that the program will execute the fathers' functions in the reversed order printed by .mro() ?

Comment: MRO (method resolution order) is the order in what classes inherit each other. It's easy if there are just 3 classes but when there are huge amount of classes and all them are intertwined with inheritance in a way that only devil can understand it then MRO is created by special rules. in case of python.3X this rules are called C3 linarization algorithm.

Comment: when by calling `__init__` functions it 'jumps up' to  grandparent `base` it starts to 'go down' and then execution of `base`'s `__init__` is actually the execution of `super().__init__()` line from `F0` and execution `F0`'s `__init__` is actually execution of `super().__init__()` line from either `F1` or `F2`. The fact that 'F2' is printed higher points that `F2`'s `__init__` is executed before `F1`'s one.

Comment: And in this moment it should just 'go down' further to `F0` without touching `F1` but  some magic happens and it does touch `F1` and it's interesting why `F1` and `F2` here is swapped places.  I guess that the essence of that 'magic' lies somewhere in C3 linarizaion. I myself have no answer for this question and I'm curious as well as you.

Answer (score 0):

> Then if I call super().**init**() in F3 (which inherits F1 and F2), it will execute both F1 and F2's init function.

But that is the expected case right, since:

```py
class F3(F1, F2):
    ...
```

`Base_3` inherits from both classes.

Comment: That is not my expected case (though it is wrong), since refer to the 7-th and 8-th lines of the outputl, though Base_3 inherits from Base_1 and Base_2, it only executes Base_1's init function.

Comment: Is this answer confusing F3 with Base3?

Comment: I did indeed, but still what is the expected behavior here?

Comment: My expected output of "f3 = F3()" will be "
base
F0
F1
"
(in which there is no F2 printed)

Comment: `F3` and `Base3` inherit from `F1`,`F2` and `Base1`, `Base2`, respectively. But `F3.__init__`'s `super` calls both F1 and F2, while  `base_3.__init__`'s `super` only calls `base_1.__init__()`. The difference is that the F* hierarchy is a diamond -- both inherit from F0 and base -- whereas the base* hierarchy just terminates at base_1 and base_2.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Could you explain a little more detailed? Why terminating at base_1 and base_2 means that super().__init__() in base_3 only executed base_1's init function, and why F2's init function is executed (because F2 inherits from F0)? From the logic I see in Base_1,2,3's example, the init function order of "f3=F3()" will be just base's, F0's and F1's  (no F2's).